# Writing to File with Offset

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to write a simple block of code that writes the contents of an array to a position in a file. The file is a simple, text only file. It seems to do everything write, but file contents end up in hex (with a bunch of zeroes at the beginning). I'm using the following:

```
FILE * fp; // file to write to
void fwritel(long offset, char * data) {
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");  
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(data, 1, strlen(data) - 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I've also used a variation of `pwrite` that didn't work: `pwrite(fp, data, strlen(data) - 1, offset);` The code I'm looking for would write `data` at position `offset` only modifying the file from `offset` to `offset + strlen(data)`.

Comment: Read more about [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and its open modes!

Comment: What do you expect? Seeking to a position in a file and then writing fills the gap, if there is any, with zeros. Your text editor sees these zeros and thinks it is binary data, which it displays as hex. If you want to prepend the string with spaces, `fputc(' ')` `offset` times instead of seeking.

Comment: Perhaps `fprintf` would be of more use to you? If you are creating a formatted text file, that will help keep non-printable characters out of your file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multiple part fix:

1. Joachim Pilebord is right. Opening the file using `fopen(file, "w")` will destroy the contents of the file. So each time it would open the file, zero the file, then write the new contents.
2. M Oehm was also correct, the new content would be padded with zeros - thus Sublime treated it as hex.

So, opening the file once, somewhere at the beginning of the program, using only

```
fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(data, 1, strlen(data), fp);
```

and closing the file somewhere near the end of the program produces the correct output. Using `fputc(' ')` would work but you'd need to make sure I'm not replacing characters that you need (i.e. previously placed data in those parts of the file).